# In Nrf24lO1 pa+Lna,is there any indication led light?

Tags: nrf24l01+

How do I know that my **Nrf24lO1 pa+Lna **  is working or not? For that any separate led is there for on ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no led.

But you can use the [isChipConnected](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#ac224c55270d26dbe7b4f3492ea3056b5) function in the [RF24 library](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24)